# Coffeescript json response processing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I just starting with coffeescript. However, I have to process a `JSON` response from a rails app to generate google map markers. How do I parse the `JSON` data into the coffeescript.

Code looks like this:

```js
  $.ajax '/locations',
          type: 'GET'
          dataType: 'json'
          error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
              alert "error"
          success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
              buses = data

  window.initMap = ->
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      center:
        lat: 0.324680
        lng: 32.572633
      zoom: 11
    )
  if buses?
    for i in buses
      marker = new google.maps.Marker(position: new google.maps.LatLng(i["latitude"], i["longitude"])
      map: map
      title: i["number_plate"])
      marker.setMap(map)

  loadScript = ->
    script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript"
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
    document.getElementById('map_scripts').appendChild script
    return

  loadScript()
```

The Json response looks like this  `{"locations":[{"number_plate":"UAW796N","terminal_number":2,"latitude":"0.4122","longitude":"33.235","speed":"46.0"}]}`

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`, the same way if you were writing Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `__ 'locations.number_plate'`.